# Invoking Chrome browser to render landing page after ad clicked in app using Android webview

Tags: android-webview, mobile-website, mobilewebforms

I am running ads in mobile apps to drive traffic to my site.  Much of that traffic is being rendered in Android Webview.  I want to force the mobile app to open the Chrome browser to render my site after my ad is clicked in the app even if webview is being used at the time the ad is clicked.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!